# Running new() inside my contract adds 20K to contract size?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I created a function where one of my contracts instantiates another and it suddenly pushed the whole contract over the size limit.  Here's the function:

```
function createContract(E.BKLiteMeta memory meta)         
          public 
          payable
          returns(address) 
    {
        require(meta.publisherAddress == msg.sender, "only pub");
        return(address(new BKopyLite(meta)));
    }
```

Hardhat `size-contracts` reports the size of the contract 24.02.  When I change the function to:

```
function createContract(E.BKLiteMeta memory meta)         
          public 
          payable
          returns(address) 
    {
        require(meta.publisherAddress == msg.sender, "only pub");
        return(address(0);
    }
```

`size-contracts' reports a size of 4.68.  So about 20K increase in size by calling new?  Can someone explain, and sugggest a workaround?  (The contract size of the BKopyLite contract is about 17k)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `new` keyword results in a new contract being deployed and this requires access to its bytecode. To do this the compiler embeds `BKopyLite`'s bytecode inside the parent contract. If the contract to be deployed is fairly big, it can add a lot to the size of the parent contract.

There are ways to avoid that:

- You could for example have a special factory contract, whose only job is deploying copies of `BKopyLite`. The parent contract would make an external call to it to trigger deployment of `BKopyLite` and receive an address of a new instance in return.
- You could deploy a single instance of the contract and use OpenZeppelin's [Clones](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/proxy#Clones) to create lightweight "copies". The copies would actually be proxy contracts that have their own storage and let the single instance operate on it via DELEGATECALL.

Comment: This comment just helped me realize why my contract size kept ballooning into the skies. Thanks @cameel.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to expand on @cameel's answer which was very useful to me but took me a bit to understand.

I had a `Wrapper` contract which deployed instances of some contract `ContractC`. That means `Wrapper` calls `new ContractC()` and it takes all of `ContractC`'s size. Not cool, it took me over the limit.

So I added a `Deployer` on the middle, who has a single method to deploy instances of `ContractC` and can only be called by `Wrapper`. I also added an interface for `Deployer`: `IDeployer`, which includes only the deploy method.

`Wrapper` keeps having all the validation logic but now does `IDeployer(d_instance).deploy()` instead of calling `new`, so it only needs to add the bytes of `IDeployer`, which are few. `Wrapper` now is way below the limit.

Init flow looks like this:

- I deploy an instance of `Wrapper` and `Deployer` -> `wrapper` and `deployer`.
- I tell `deployer` that only `wrapper` can call it, and I tell `Wrapper` who it's deployer partner is (`deployer`).

On every future call the flow is:

- User calls `wrapper.deploy()`
- `wrapper` does some validations
- `wrapper` calls `deployer.deploy()`
- `deployer` calls `contractC = new ContractC()`
- `deployer` transfers ownership of `contractC` back to `wrapper` and returns it's address.
- `wrapper` does some more logic with `contractC`'s address
- Everyone is happy.